# Как составить шаблон для проверки наличия числа в строке?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка из разных чисел, разделенных через пробел: `"21 22 1 13 25"`. Мне нужно составить шаблон, в который я передам число и смогу проверить, есть ли оно в строке. Я пробовал делать так: `new RegExp('\\s{1}' + number + '\\s{1}')`. Но этот вариант не приемлем, тк первое и последнее число содержат только один пробел - слева или справа, соответственно они не подходят под шаблон.

Comment: числа состоят только из цифр? или могут быть например дробные: `2.2` или в экспоненциальной форме: 1e-10?

Comment: только из цифр.

Comment: @EvgeniiZaets мне нравится ответ Darth, но вам же ничего не мешает добавить пробелы в начало и конец строки, чтобы ваш вариант работал

Comment: Нельзя добавлять пробелы, тк строка должна позже обрабатываться именно в таком виде.

Comment: так не портите строку совсем. временную сделайте :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для случая когда в строке есть только цифры можно воспользоваться [спец символом \b](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-word-boundary)

```js
function test(number) {
  return {
    [number]: new RegExp('\\b' + number + '\\b').test(numbers.join(' '))
  }
}
var numbers = [21, 22, 1, 13, 25];
var wrongNumbers = [11, 17, 255];
var result = numbers.map(test).concat(wrongNumbers.map(test));

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, null, 2) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Зачем насиловать регуляркой, когда проще решить как в ответе @Darth ?

Comment: @Other, регулярка предоставляет больше возможностей для определения границ числа

Comment: Ну регуляркой можно и HTML распарсить, если очень захотеть, но здесь и сейчас задача другая вроде. Просто стало интересно - может Вы знали хорошую причину для использования тернистого пути регулярок.

Comment: @Other, не такой уж он и тернистый в данном случае

Comment: Как по мне, так любое употребление регулярных выражений - это как бить взведённый снаряд: взрыва может и не будет, но может и...

Comment: @Other, так можно сказать о любом использовании технологии в которой плохо разобрался

Comment: Почему плохо? Просто вещь не самая очевидная, вероятность забыть скобочку весьма большая.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38625/discussion-between-grundy-and-other).

Answer (score 3):

```
var numbers_string='21 22 1 13 25', number = 22;
if(numbers_string.split(' ').indexOf(number) != -1) //число есть в строке
else //его там нет
```

Comment: либо (' '+numbers_string+' ').indexOf(number)  - то есть не сплитить, а наоборот обрамить разделителями

Comment: @ЕвгенийБорисов если не спилитить, то поиск будет по строке и он число 2 найдет в числе 22 - неправильный результат

Comment: ну дык и искомое обрамить. Дел-то.  (' '+numbers_string+' ').indexOf((' '+number+' ')). Вполне себе альтернатива. А уж если строка в которой ведётся поиск уже с разделителями по краям, то всё становится ещё веселее.

Comment: @ЕвгенийБорисов не понял что за разделители вы имеете в виду.. вы в курсе что `''+numbers_string+'' === numbers_string`?

Comment: @Darth, там пробел между кавычками

Answer (score 0):

Вот так можно

```
(\s+|^)21(\s+|$)
```

https://regex101.com/r/xQ7nN8/1